# Limit dropzone.js file upload

Tags: file-upload, limit, dropzone.js

I'm trying to limit the file uploads to allow uploading only 1 file. I'm pretty sure this has something to do with altering the selectedfiles callback, but haven't gotten it to work yet. Has anyone solved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but you are correct, you need to add this.removeAllFiles(); under the selectedfiles callback.

Comment: Still looking for an answer.... I tried adding the function as you suggested, it doesn't solve the problem... code --                                                  selectedfiles: function(files) {
 this.removeAllFiles();  
        if (this.element === this.previewsContainer) {
          return this.element.classList.add("started");
        }
      },

Comment: Yes, sorry, another thing I changed was parallelUploads: 1; (Before it was 2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer ftfish, but I changed the parallelUploads and it still isn't working...

Comment: Can you please post the exact code that you changed in dropzone.js?

Comment: That's actually very interesting, I downloaded the original dropzone.js file and did these exact changes and it worked... (Tried only on Chrome).

This is the js file: http://fourtonfish.com/thisis.me/js/dropzone.js

In case you'll want to look at the page using it (where it works), please keep in mind this is work in progress - and seems to only work in Chrome right now.

Comment: Glad that I could help :) By the way, I added one extra option - elToUpdate. You can remove all instances of this, I only used this to reference the element which will use the uploaded image as a background.